# Defining own Devise controllers prevents Devise using custom views

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, controller, devise, routes

I used `config.scoped_views = true` in `initializers/devise.rb` to make Devise use my own views rather than its default views for my two roles (Admin and Subscriber). This worked great, and I went ahead and customized my views.

Then earlier today I added my own controllers that subclass Devise's controllers and told devise to use these controllers in `routes.rb` using:

```
  devise_for :subscribers, :controllers => { 
    :registrations => "subscriber_registrations",
    :sessions => "subscriber_sessions",
    :passwords => "subscriber_sessions"
  }
```

This works nicely, however it seems to have had the unwanted side-effect of making Devise revert back to using its default views for my Subscribers role.

In my logs when I load the login page for Subscribers I can see this:

```
 Rendered /Users/myName/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/devise-2.1.0/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb
```

Am I doing something wrong? Do I now need to manually add all the view rendering because I've defined my own controllers?